# Selecting has_many with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following associations:

```
class User
  has_many :orders
  has_many :events
end

class Event
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :orders
end

class Order
  belongs_to :event
end
```

My problem is that when doing User.last.events.orders I get nothing, while User.last.events.last.orders is resulting with stuff (last is just something I picked to test it)

What is the problem?

Be aware that the User has Order, but Users that have Event, can have Orders from other Users...

thats what I'm trying to get here.

Thanks!

Comment: `user.events.flat_map(&:orders).uniq` will get you all orders related to this user (`array.flat_map(&:orders)` calls the method `orders` on each element of `array`) -- it can be slow to perform this instruction, depending on the orders count & events count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.last.events` is a *collection* of events, so there should be no `orders` method and `User.last-events.orders` should generate a `no method error`.

I noticed also that you didn't have a `belongs_to :user` declaration on your `Order`, even though you have `has_many :orders` on `User`.

Answer (score 2):

`User.first.events` gives you the array of events associated with the specified user record (in this case first, in your case last)

So when you call `User.first.events.orders` you probably get a 'noMethod orders' error.

And `User.first.events.last.order` will give you the orders associated with the last event of the first user.

If you want orders from events that are not for that User you will have to have a more complex query.